# mysql stored procedures and parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have a stored procedure which selects from a certain table. This table gets passed to the procedure as a parameter.
            SELECT * FROM ParamName
And all it tells me when I try to run it is 'Table ParamName doesn't exist.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated?

Comment: Try passing "DataBaseName.TableName" as ParamName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParamName` by itself would appear to MySQL as a table/field name, which it's rightly complaining about. If Paramname is a parameter for the stored procedure, you'd have to use `@ParamName` to tell MySQL to look for a variable of that name.

However, you can't simply do

```
SELECT * FROM @ParamName
```

mysql doesn't allow table/fieldnames to be specified via variables. You'll have to prepare a statement first:

```
SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @ParamName);
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s1;
```